# Probability in coin toss

Tags: probability

Suppose that you have a fair coin. You start with $\$0$. You win $\$1$ each time you get a head and loose $\$1$ each time you get tails. Calculate the probability of getting $\$2$ without getting below $\$0$ at any time.

Comment: Hint:  You get to $2$ if you toss two Heads in a row preceded by any number (including none) of pairs of tosses in which you toss a Head followed by a Tail. So, winning sequences are HH, HTHH, HTHTHH, HTHTHTHH, ....   Can you calculate the probabilities of these and add them up? Along the way you might want to think of why adding the probabilities is appropriate, and also think about using geometric series and the like instead of a calculator in arriving at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly 2$ you must have a run consisting of succesive pairs of (1,-1) followed by (1,1).

For an arbitrary but fixed n, n even, You have 2^n different runs.

Now, you get 2$ if your run begins with (1,1) the rest, 2^(n-2) digits, is arbitrary. Therefore you have 2^(n-2) successes out of 2^n events which yields 2^(n-2)/(2^n) = 1/2^2.

If Your run begins with (1,-1) followed by (1,1) you have 2^(n-4) successes out of 2^n events which yields 2^(n-4)/(2^n) = 1/2^4, etc. etc.

For an arbitrary but fixed n, n even, the probability to win 2$ is the sum s(n)=1/2^n + 1/(2^{n-2)+ ....+1/2^2. The Limes of s(n), n-> infinity is 1/3.

Comment: This works, too :-) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$P$(getting \$$2$ without getting below \$$0$) =

$P$(getting \$$2$ without getting below \$$0$ in $2$ tosses) +

$P$(getting \$$2$ without getting below \$$0$ in $4$ tosses) +

$P$(getting \$$2$ without getting below \$$0$ in $6$ tosses) + $\ldots$

= $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{64} + \ldots$

= $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: I didn't understand what you were trying to say until I read [Fritz Mustermann's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/475141).

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Approach**

Suppose the probability of winning from $0$ is $p$. That would be $\frac12$ the probability of winning from $1$ plus $\frac12$ the probability of winning from $-1$ (which is $0$). The probability of winning from $1$ is $\frac12$ the probability of winning from $2$ (which is $1$) plus $\frac12$ the probability of winning from $0$ (which is $p$). Thus,
$$
p=\frac12\overbrace{\left(\frac12\cdot1+\frac12p\right)}^{\begin{array}{c}\text{probability of}\\\text{winning from $1$}\end{array}}+\frac12\cdot0
$$
Solve for $p=\frac13$.

---

**State Machine**

Each column of the following matrix represents what happens to each state:

At $2$, the state stays at $2$ (i.e. the game is over)
At $1$, there is $\frac12$ chance to go to $0$ and $\frac12$ chance to go to $2$
At $0$, there is $\frac12$ chance to go to $-1$ and $\frac12$ chance to go to $1$
At $-1$, the state stays at $-1$ (i.e. the game is over)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\tfrac12&0&0\\
0&0&\tfrac12&0\\
0&\tfrac12&0&0\\
0&0&\tfrac12&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
S_2\vphantom{\tfrac12}\\S_1\vphantom{\tfrac12}\\S_0\vphantom{\tfrac12}\\S_{-1}\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
S_2'\vphantom{\tfrac12}\\S_1'\vphantom{\tfrac12}\\S_0'\vphantom{\tfrac12}\\S_{-1}'\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Decomposing the matrix into the [Jordan Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\tfrac12&0&0\\
0&0&\tfrac12&0\\
0&\tfrac12&0&0\\
0&0&\tfrac12&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
$$
To see where the state ends up in the limit, we raise the matrix to an ever greater power, which leaves the unit eigenvalues and eliminates the smaller eigenvalues:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 & \tfrac{2}{3} & \color{#C00000}{\tfrac{1}{3}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \color{#C00000}{0} & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & \color{#C00000}{0} & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & \tfrac{1}{3} & \color{#C00000}{\tfrac{2}{3}} & 1
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \color{#C00000}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & \color{#C00000}{1} & 0 & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & \color{#C00000}{0} & 0\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#C00000}{0}\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & -1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
$$
The third column tells what happens if we start at $0$: there is a $\frac13$ chance of ending up at $2$ and a $\frac23$ chance of ending up at $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $P_i$ the probability to obtain $\$2$ when you have $\$i$, then we look for $P_0$. So a recurrence can be

$$P_{i}=\frac{1}{2}P_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2}P_{i+1}$$

with $P_2=1$ and $P_{-1}=0$ because we do not allow a score below of $\$0$. Now

$$P_0=\frac{1}{2}P_{-1} + \frac{1}{2}P_{1}=\frac{1}{2}P_{1},$$
$$P_1=\frac{1}{2}P_{0} + \frac{1}{2}P_{2}=\frac{1}{2}P_{0} + \frac{1}{2}$$

therefore

$$P_0=\frac{1}{2}P_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}P_{0} + \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

and $P_0=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Good argument. It looks somehow familiar...

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful and, if you think, can be expanded to more general cases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first two tosses of the coin. There are $4$ equally likely outcomes
$HH, HT, TH, TT$, and you have won if the outcome is $HH$ and lost if the outcome
is $TH$ or $TT$. Else, the outcome is $HT$ and you are back to Square One and
must toss the coin again to determine whether you will win $2$ before
your wealth reduces below $0$.

So consider the *very first time* that the outcome is *not* $HT$. Then,
*conditioned* on the event $A = \{HH, TH, TT\}$, the conditional
probability of winning is
$$P(HH \mid A) = \frac{P(HH \mid A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(HH)}{P(A)} 
= \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

---

Alternatively, as I suggested in a comment on the main question,
a win occurs exactly when the successive tosses result in
$HH, HTHH, HTHTHH, \ldots$ which have probabilities 
$\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{64}, \ldots$ and thus
$$\begin{align}
P(2~\text{before}~ -1) &= P\{HH, HTHH, HTHTHH, \ldots\}\\
&= P(HH) + P(HTHH) + P(HTHTHH) + \cdots & \text{third axiom}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n}
= \frac{1}{4}\times \frac{1}{1 - \frac 14} =\frac 13.
\end{align}$$